# Mistake when you press on an item in ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, textview

The list shows the information from the database. When selecting items in the ListView TextView transmitted only item which is first in the list. What you need to alter the code to be displayed in the TextView is selected item from the list?

ContactMain.java

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class ContactMain extends ListActivity implements
        LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private ContactDBmoy cqh;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE = 0;
//  private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT = 1;
    private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;

    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    private ListView contactListView; // встроенный в ListActivity элемент
    // ListView



    public final String name_contact = ContactDBmoy.COLUMN_NAME;
    public final String phone = ContactDBmoy.COLUMN_PHONE;
    public final String birthday = ContactDBmoy.COLUMN_BIRTHDAY;
    public final String passport_sn = ContactDBmoy.COLUMN_PASSPORT_SN;
    public final String adress = ContactDBmoy.COLUMN_ADRESS;
    public final String site = ContactDBmoy.COLUMN_SITE;

    public static final String rowId = "rowId"; // ключ для передачи в другую
    // активность

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact_list);

        contactListView = getListView(); // доступ к встроенному ListView
        contactListView.setOnItemClickListener(viewContactListener);

        this.getListView().setDividerHeight(2);
        cqh = new ContactDBmoy(this);

        fillData();
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        // Первоначальный способ. Тоже работает
        // Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getAllTodos();
        // adapter.changeCursor(cursor);

        getLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_contact, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // Реакция на выбор меню
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.insert:
            createNewTask();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.insert:
            createNewTask();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete_contact);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case DELETE_ID:

            // получаем из пункта контекстного меню данные по пункту списка
            AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                    .getMenuInfo();

            // извлекаем id записи и удаляем соответствующую запись в БД
            cqh.deleteContact(info.id);

            // получаем новый курсор с данными
            getLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();

            // fillData();

            return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void createNewTask() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Contact.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
    }

    private void fillData() {
        // cursor = sqh.getAllKvart();
        // startManagingCursor(cursor);

        String[] from = new String[] { name_contact, phone };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.contact_name, R.id.contact_phone };

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contact_row, null,
                from, to, 0);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // создаем лоадер для чтения данных
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();

    }


    // слушатель события, которое отвечает на выбор имени контакта в ListView
        OnItemClickListener viewContactListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position,
                    long id) {
                // создание Intent для запуска ViewContact Activity
                Intent viewContact = new Intent(ContactMain.this, ViewContactMoy.class);

                // передача ID строки выбранного контакта в качестве
                // расширения объекта Intent
                viewContact.putExtra(rowId, id);
                startActivity(viewContact); // start the ViewContact Activity
            }
        };


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            fillData();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (cqh != null) {
            cqh.close();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new MyCursorLoader(this, cqh);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        adapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {
        ContactDBmoy cqh;

        public MyCursorLoader(Context context, ContactDBmoy db) {
            super(context);
            this.cqh = db;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            Cursor cursor = cqh.getAllContact();

            return cursor;
        }
    }
}
```

ContactDBmoy.java - my DB

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.util.Log;

public class ContactDBmoy extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements BaseColumns {

    // константы для конструктора
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contact_db.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "contact_table";

    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name_contact";
    public static final String COLUMN_PHONE = "phone";
    public static final String COLUMN_BIRTHDAY = "birthday";
    public static final String COLUMN_PASSPORT_SN = "passport_sn";
    public static final String COLUMN_ADRESS = "adress";
    public static final String COLUMN_SITE = "site";

    ContactDBmoy cqh;
    SQLiteDatabase sdb;

    private static final String SQL_CREATE_CONTACTS = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_NAME + " (" + BaseColumns._ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_NAME + " text not null, " + COLUMN_PHONE
            + " text not null, " + COLUMN_BIRTHDAY + " integer, "
            + COLUMN_PASSPORT_SN + " text not null, " + COLUMN_ADRESS + " text not null, "
            + COLUMN_SITE + " text not null " + ");";


    private static final String SQL_DELETE_CONTACTS = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "
            + TABLE_NAME;


    public ContactDBmoy(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public ContactDBmoy(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
            int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION, errorHandler);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_CONTACTS);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w(ContactDBmoy.class.getName(), "Обновление базы данных с версии " + oldVersion
                + " до версии " + newVersion
                + ", которое удалит все старые данные");
        // Удаляем предыдущую таблицу при апгрейде
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_CONTACTS);

        // Создаём новый экземпляр таблицы
        onCreate(db);
    }


    /**
     * Создаёт новый элемент списка. Если создан успешно - возвращается
     * номер строки rowId, иначе -1
     */


    public long createNewContact(String name_contact, String phone, String birthday, String passport_sn, String adress, String site) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues initialValues = createContentValues( name_contact, phone, birthday, passport_sn, adress, site);


    long row = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, initialValues);
    db.close();

    return row;

}

    /**
     * Обновляет список
     */

    public boolean updateContact(long rowId, String name_contact, String phone, String birthday, String passport_sn, String adress, String site) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues updateValues = createContentValues(name_contact, phone, birthday, passport_sn, adress, site);

        return db.update(TABLE_NAME, updateValues, _ID + "=" + rowId,
                null) > 0;
    }


    /**
     * Удаляет элемент списка
     */
    public void deleteContact(long rowId) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, _ID + "=" + rowId, null);
        db.close();
    }



    /**
     * Возвращает курсор со всеми элементами списка 
     * 
     * @return курсор с результатами всех записей
     */
    public Cursor getAllContact() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { BaseColumns._ID, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_PHONE, COLUMN_BIRTHDAY, COLUMN_PASSPORT_SN, COLUMN_ADRESS, COLUMN_SITE
     }, null,
                null, null, null, null);
    }


    /**
     * Возвращает курсор с указанной записи
     */
    public Cursor getOneContact(long rowId) throws SQLException {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
//      Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, TABLE_NAME,
//              new String[] { COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_PHONE, COLUMN_BIRTHDAY, COLUMN_PASSPORT_SN, COLUMN_ADRESS, COLUMN_SITE }, _ID + "=" + rowId, null,
//              null, null, null, null);
//      if (mCursor != null) {
//          mCursor.moveToFirst();
//      }
        return db.query("contact_table", null, "_id=" + _ID, null, null, null,
                null);
    }



    /*
     * Создаёт пару ключ-значение и записывает в базу
     */

    private ContentValues createContentValues(String name_contact, String phone, String birthday, String passport_sn, String adress, String site) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, name_contact);
        cv.put(COLUMN_PHONE, phone);
        cv.put(COLUMN_BIRTHDAY, birthday);
        cv.put(COLUMN_PASSPORT_SN, passport_sn);
        cv.put(COLUMN_ADRESS, adress);
        cv.put(COLUMN_SITE, site);
        return cv;
    }
}
```

ViewContactMoy.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ViewContactMoy extends Activity {

    private long rowId; // имя выбранного контакта
    private TextView nameTV; // отображает имя контакта
    private TextView phoneTV; // номер телефона контакта
    private TextView birthdayTV; // дата рождения контакта
    private TextView passportTV; // паспортные данные контакта
    private TextView adressTV; // адрес прописки контакта
    private TextView siteTV; // адрес прописки контакта

    ContactDBmoy cqh;
    SQLiteDatabase sdb;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact_view_moy);

        nameTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameTV);
        phoneTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phoneTV);
        birthdayTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.birthdayTV);
        passportTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.passportTV);
        adressTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.adressTV);
        siteTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.siteTV);

        // получение ID строки выбранного контакта

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        rowId = extras.getLong(ContactMain.rowId);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // создание нового класса LoadContactTask и вызов его
        new LoadContactTask().execute(rowId);
    }

    // выполняет запрос к базе данных за пределами потока GUI
    private class LoadContactTask extends AsyncTask<Long, Object, Cursor> {
        ContactDBmoy cqh = new ContactDBmoy(ViewContactMoy.this);

        // выполнение доступа к базе данных
        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(Long... params) {
            sdb = cqh.getWritableDatabase();
            sdb = cqh.getReadableDatabase();

            // получение курсора, содержащего все данные выбранной записи
            return cqh.getOneContact(params[0]);
        }

        // использование объекта типа Cursor, возвращаемого методом
        // doInBackground
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor mCursor) {
            super.onPostExecute(mCursor);

            mCursor.moveToFirst(); // перемещение к первому элементу

                // получение индекса столбца для каждого элемента  данных

                int nameIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactDBmoy.COLUMN_NAME);
                int phoneIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactDBmoy.COLUMN_PHONE);
                int birthdayIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactDBmoy.COLUMN_BIRTHDAY);
                int passportIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactDBmoy.COLUMN_PASSPORT_SN);
                int adressIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactDBmoy.COLUMN_ADRESS);
                int siteIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactDBmoy.COLUMN_SITE);

                // заполнение компонентов TextViews выбранными данными
                nameTV.setText(mCursor.getString(nameIndex));
                phoneTV.setText(mCursor.getString(phoneIndex));
                birthdayTV.setText(mCursor.getString(birthdayIndex));
                passportTV.setText(mCursor.getString(passportIndex));
                adressTV.setText(mCursor.getString(adressIndex));
                siteTV.setText(mCursor.getString(siteIndex));


            mCursor.close(); // закрытие курсора результата
            sdb.close(); // закрытие подключения к базе данных

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.view_contact_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.editItem:
            // создание Intent для запуска AddEditContact
            Intent addEditContact = new Intent(this, Contact.class);

            // передача данных выбранного контакта
            addEditContact.putExtra(ContactDBmoy._ID, rowId);
            addEditContact.putExtra("name", nameTV.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("phone", phoneTV.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("birthday", birthdayTV.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("passport_sn", passportTV.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("adress", adressTV.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("site", siteTV.getText());
            startActivity(addEditContact);
            return true;

        case R.id.deleteItem:
            deleteContact(); // удаление отображенного контакта
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    // удаление контакта
    private void deleteContact() {
        // создание нового AlertDialog Builder
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewContactMoy.this);

        builder.setTitle(R.string.confirmTitle);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.confirmMessage);

        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_delete,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button) {
                        final ContactDBmoy cqh = new ContactDBmoy(
                                ViewContactMoy.this);

                        // создание класса AsyncTask, удаляющего контакт
                        // из другого потока, после удаления вызывается finish
                        AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object> deleteTask = new AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object>() {
                            @Override
                            protected Object doInBackground(Long... params) {
                                cqh.deleteContact(params[0]);
                                return null;
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
                                finish(); // возврат в AddressBook
                            }
                        };

                        // вызов класса AsyncTask для удаления контакта с rowID
                        deleteTask.execute(new Long[] { rowId });
                    }
                });

        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.button_cancel, null);
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all tell me you getting values into your `LoadContactTask()` debug it and print values into logcat

Comment: No, logcat writes nothing except:  Skipped 418 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.